# Oracle Forms: Problem with master/detail commit

Tags: oracle, forms, commit, master-detail

greetings,I'm facing a problem in Oracle Forms 10g. I created a simple master-detail form where i want to save data only from the detail data block (the master will function more as a browser).

The only solution found till now is to edit the properties of text items in the master block and prevent them from inserting/updating. This comes in conflict with the list of values (LOV) appearing when the user tries to input the app_id, or from a search button (i know that the way is not significant). Is there a way that i can pass values to the primary block and function only as a query?

Any help could save me from lots of trouble!

Comment: Is the user able to navigate between master records e.g. using Up and Down buttons?  Or do they just select one master record at a time?

Answer (score 0):

We can set various properties at *the block level* using the Block Properties palette.  In your case you need to toggle off **Delete Allowed**, **Insert Allowed** and **Update Allowed**.  Obviously you will want **Query Allowed** toggled on.

Comment: the case is that LOV does not return a query, but values to the text items, so if insert or update are disallowed in master block there is no way that the LOV will work. I'm looking on how i can override it..